# How to select data from another sql server server tables in sql script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to know how to query data from another SQL Server instances' tables in SQL script.

I am writing sql script running on `127.0.0.1\SQLINSTANCE1` but inside the script there is going to select data from `127.0.0.2\SQLINSTANCE2` then return the result data as part of calculation.

After googled, there seems uses the `sp_addlinkedserver` and `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` stored procedures for doing that, but unfortunately there is no complete sample working.

I have some work here but not working as expected. For example, when it was executed once more then there would pop up some error like the server already linked. But how I can execute this script for linking the server and then abandoning it?

```
DECLARE @remoteserver VARCHAR = '127.0.0.2\SQLINSTANCE2';

EXEC master.sys.sp_addlinkedserver  @server = @remoteserver
                                ,   @srvproduct = 'SQL Server';

EXEC master.sys.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin    @rmtsrvname = @remoteserver
                                    ,   @useself = 'false'
                                    ,   @locallogin = NULL
                                    ,   @rmtuser = 'sa'
                                    ,   @rmtpassword = 'password';
```

To the other side, how can I create an alias for this ugly remoteserver name?
I rather to use some elegant name like RS in `select * from [RS].[db].[dbo].[table]`

Comment: Why do you need to "abandon" the linked server? Can't you just create the linked server once, and just use it in script every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use the

```
OPENDATASOURCE
```

or

```
OPENROWSET
```

Note that you have to turn on the ad hoc distributed queries option:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OPENROWSET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) so you won't have to make and delete a linked server.

Comment: the sp_configure syntax in Jebus89 answer is helpful btw.